# javascript for loop to navigate sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to create a navigation using a for loop, in actionscript I usually use the for loop to do this. I'd like to assign each link the same action (scrollTop) but with different target (#sec1, #sec2 ...). But in javascript I don't understand where I'm wrong.

An example:

```
var Secs = [
    "sec1",
    "sec2",
    "sec3",
    "sec4",
    "sec5",
    "sec6"
];

for(var i = 0; i < Secs.length; i++){
    $("." + this.Secs).click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#" + this.Secs).offset().top}, 700);
    });
}
```

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `this.Secs` - *as `Secs` is an array you can use `Secs[i]` like this*

```
 $("." + Secs[i]).click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#" + Secs[i]).offset().top}, 700);
 });
```